# ASPNET Core How to Update Multiple Records Using Chekboxes

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple ASPNET core Razor WEB App. 
In this I have a the following Model classes

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RegID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? SectionID { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
}
public class Section
{
    public int  ID { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }


}
```

What I want to Create is a razor page where I can select a Section, and Select multiple students and Submit to Update All the selected students with the new selected sections. 
Any kind of Help will be appreciated, Even ones with MVC solution. 
Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far with Razor?

Comment: I am very new to the .Net framework, 
So not much,